# Facebook event sync externally?

Tags: facebook

A problem I have is that for years now people have signed/registered up to our event (LAN party) via our own website using our simple signup system, this has been great however times are slowly changing and we've had to also create a Facebook event that helps numbers. However we end up with two different lists of people. On event day we've a print out of the registered people as we do hit the limit and only can let in people who have registered/booked seats.

I'm trying to work out a way to have perhaps an app on Facebook that allows people to sign up for an event via our page that would fire off an external (jsonp/xml?) request to our sign and would sign them up there as well.

Only basic info is needed, a gamer tag and sign up date..

I have the skills to do this but unsure if Facebook even allows you to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

tl;tr
basically two sign up locations but one database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook allows this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Comment: Hi, I found that in my search earlier. It seems to do what I want but it requires the back end to be at facebook. Should I look at creating a "custom app"?

Comment: You need to create a Facebook app. This is the only way to receive access tokens from Facebook which will be required to write and read data from Facebook.

Comment: The link you posted is quite lengthy. What specifically should I be looking for?